# Git actions with RascalMPL

Tags: github-actions, rascal

How can I setup github actions in my rascal project, I saw something like that in the [cwi-swat/python](https://github.com/cwi-swat/python-air/blob/main/.github/workflows/build.yaml) project, I wanted to know how to set that up? Any resource will be appreciated.

Comment: You can always peak at the `.github` folder;) and the rest is all in the maven setup, namely the rascal-maven-plugin.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I tie my rascal tests (ie., `test <function-decl>`) to the action is what i want to know